# Data Tables responsive

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datatables

**Tengo una tabla como la siguiente**, estoy utilizando la extensión de jQuery DataTables.

[image: Datatables]

**Intento hacerla responsive**, es decir en primera instancia en pantalla completa se deberia ver todas las columnas, **ahora a medida que se valla reduciendo el tamaño de mi tabla deseo que siempre se muestren las columnas que he marcado en la imagen (ID,Título y Acciones)**, las demás pueden estar ocultas.

He intentado lo siguiente: (Configuración de mi tabla)

```
   <script>
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
          
            responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                targets: -1,
            }
            },
            columnDefs: [ {
                className: 'control',
                orderable: false,              
                targets:   -1,
            } ],                
          
            ...
            ...
  <script>
```

**Con esto en pantalla completa no me aparece la columna acciones**.
Por favor alguien que me ayude, para que mi tabla sea responsiva en todos lo tamaños y poder mostrar las columnas indicadas en la imagen (ID,Título y Acciones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes utilizar el atributo *responsivePriority* en las definiciones de columnas, así:

```
    $('#tabla').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 4 },
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -2 }
        ]
    } );
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario fue mi solucion